# Inversion of lines and circles using explicit parametrizations

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-inversion

Is there a way to parametrize a line and a circle in the complex plane [by $z = z(t)$], to show that under the inversion function $f(z) = 1/z$, a line is mapped either to a line or a circle, and a circle is mapped either to a line or a circle?

This is simple in the case of translations or dilations: For example, parametrizing a circle by $z(t) = z_0 + Re^{it}$, under the dilation $f(z) = az$, $f[z(t)] = az_0 + aRe^{it}$, which is still the parametrization of a circle.

Comment: using parametrizations instead of equations for this is really not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it won't be easy, because a line parameterized by 
$$
L(t) = a + bt
$$
will map to a circle that's parameterized by 
$$
C(s) = z_0 + Re^{is}
$$
where $s$ and $t$ are related by some relatively complicated function. In particular, the relationship between $t$ and $s$ is certainly not linear, for the line is traversed once as $t$ ranges over the real line, while the circle is traversed infinitely often as $t$ ranges over the real line. So that map that expresses $s$ as a function of $t$ must take the whole real line to something like the interval $-\pi < s < \pi$.

In short: it's possible, but possibly not worth the effort. :(

Alternative short summary: While inversion takes lines and circles to lines and circles, it does not carry *standard parameterizations* of lines to standard parameterizations of circles.

Here are the details for one particular line:

$$
L(t) = 2 + it
$$
where $t \in \mathbb R$.

Then after transformation, we get the point
$$
M(t) = \frac{1}{2+it} = \frac{2 - it}{4 + t^2}
$$
This is a point of the circle whose center is at $z = \frac{1}{4} + 0i$ and whose radius is $\frac{1}{4}$. Subtracting $\frac{1}{4}$ from $M$ gives
$$
v(t) = \frac{4- t^2 - 4ti}{4(4+t^2)}
$$
as the vector from the circle-center to the point on the circle. It's not too hard to see that the squared length of $v$ is $1/4$, by direct computation and simplification.

Now $v$ points in some direction $\theta$, and since the length of $v$ is $1/2$, we know that the real and imaginary parts of $2v$ are just $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$. so 
$$
\theta = atan2(-4t, 4-t^2)
$$
and we can say that the point $\frac{1}{4} + e^{i\theta}$, under inversion, corresponds to the point $2 + ti$ on the line at $x = 2$.

Going the other way might be simpler.

Let's look at 
$$
C(s) = \frac{1}{4} (1 + e^{is})
$$
which describes a circle of radius $1/4$ around the point $z_0 = 1/4$.

Under inversion, we get
$$
D(s) = \frac{1}{C(s)} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{4} (1 + e^{is}))} = \frac{4}{1+ e^{is}} = 
\frac{4}{(1 + \cos s) + i \sin s}.
$$
Rationalizing the denominator, we get
\begin{align}
D(s) &=  
\frac{4}{(1 + \cos s) + i \sin s}\\
&= \frac{4 \left( (1 + \cos s) - i \sin s \right)}{(1 + \cos s)^2 + \sin^2 s}\\
&= \frac{4 \left( (1 + \cos s) - i \sin s \right)}{1 + 2 \cos s + \cos^2 s + \sin^2 s}\\
&= \frac{4 \left( (1 + \cos s) - i \sin s \right)}{2 + 2 \cos s}\\
&= \frac{2 \left( (1 + \cos s) - i \sin s \right)}{1 +  \cos s}\\
&= \frac{2  (1 + \cos s)}{1 +  \cos s} - i \frac{\sin s }{1 +  \cos s}\\
\end{align}
&= 2 - i \frac{\sin s }{1 +  \cos s}
\end{align}
which has the form $2 + it$ where 
$$
t = -\frac{\sin s }{1 +  \cos s}.
$$

Hence that circle is transformed into the line $\Re( z )= 2$.

As I said: probably more complicated than it's worth.

By the way, the corresponding transformation for the line $\Re(z) = 1$ turns out to be essentially the "tan(t/2)" substitution used in calculus to turn any rational function of sines and cosines into a rational function in a single real variable. You might want to write it out and see if you can figure out why they're related.

Comment: So how would you show it? Still using some sort of parametrizations...

Comment: See additions to my answer.